# Using "if let" on swiftyJSON makes my coredata assignment go awry

Tags: swift, core-data, swifty-json

I have some JSON data I'm working with on swiftyJSON.  I'm putting it into core data.  If all the fields are there, it works fine, but some of the fields are empty, and I'm trying to "protect" against the empty ones.

Here's the section of code that works just fine, if all fields are populated:

```
        // Iterate through each item in the JSON 
        for (_,subJson) in readableJSON[]["data"] {
            let title = subJson["title"].string!
            let url_title = subJson["url_title"].string!
            let entry_id = subJson["entry_id"].string!


        let newPet: NSManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Pets", inManagedObjectContext: context)

        // Store the data in CoreData "Pets"
        newPet.setValue(self.title, forKey: "title")
        newPet.setValue(url_title, forKey: "url_title")
        newPet.setValue(entry_id, forKey: "entry_id")


        } // end of "for items in JSON struck
```

But, to try and protect against an empty field, I tried doing this to the JSON iteration:

```
        if let entry_id = subJson["entry_id"].string {}
```

But when I do this, the `newPet.setValue` throw this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'entry_id'

In this case, I know that entry_id always exists, so I'm confused.

Thoughts?

Comment: It exists, but not in the same scope (`if let` creates a new scope). Use `guard let` for example.

Answer (score 1):

An `if let` statement only binds that variable within its own block:

```
if let entry_id = subJson["entry_id"].string {
    //entry_id exists in this block, and is non-nil
}
else {
    //entry_id was nil, doesn't exist
}

//entry_id doesn't exist anymore
```

If you would like to bind to that name for the parent scope, use `guard let`:

```
guard let entry_id = subJson["entry_id"].string else {
    //entry_id was nil, doesn't exist
    //you MUST break, return, or call a @noreturn function from here
}

//entry_id exists for the rest of this scope, and is non-nil
```